# WAMP Not turning green

Tags: mysql, wamp

I have installed WAMP on my 32-bit Windows 7. It was working fine for a few days but after which it started giving problems.

I suspect the problem is with MySQL because I have tested my port 80 and it is working fine. I am unable to start wampmysqld service. It throws up the error "1067- process terminated unexpectedly".

In WAMP wizard MySQL service is in green colour, so thats the indication that MySQL service has not started.
The MySQL log shows up like

```
2016-08-22 13:27:56 6020 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2016-08-22 13:27:56 6020 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count   buffer pool pages
2016-08-22 13:27:56 6020 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2016-08-22 13:27:56 6020 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2016-08-22 13:27:56 6020 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2016-08-22 13:27:56 6020 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2016-08-22 13:27:56 6020 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2016-08-22 13:27:56 6020 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 80291311 and 80291311 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 86947014 in the ib_logfiles!
2016-08-22 13:27:56 6020 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2016-08-22 13:27:56 6020 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2016-08-22 13:27:56 6020 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2016-08-22 13:27:56 6020 [ERROR] InnoDB: Attempted to open a previously opened tablespace. Previous tablespace dbzenroc/roc_changeaddress uses space ID: 435 at filepath: .\dbzenroc\roc_changeaddress.ibd. Cannot open tablespace joomla/dtfp2_updates which uses space ID: 435 at filepath: .\joomla\dtfp2_updates.ibd
InnoDB: Error: could not open single-table tablespace file .\joomla\dtfp2_updates.ibd
InnoDB: We do not continue the crash recovery, because the table may become
InnoDB: corrupt if we cannot apply the log records in the InnoDB log to it.
InnoDB: To fix the problem and start mysqld:
InnoDB: 1) If there is a permission problem in the file and mysqld cannot
InnoDB: open the file, you should modify the permissions.
InnoDB: 2) If the table is not needed, or you can restore it from a backup,
InnoDB: then you can remove the .ibd file, and InnoDB will do a normal
InnoDB: crash recovery and ignore that table.
InnoDB: 3) If the file system or the disk is broken, and you cannot remove
InnoDB: the .ibd file, you can set innodb_force_recovery > 0 in my.cnf
InnoDB: and force InnoDB to continue crash recovery here.
```

Immediate help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The error log shows where the problem lies & gives you three possible ideas for recovery - have you checked out the problem files & attempted on of the possible recovery procedures?

Answer (score 0):

Three possible fixes are given in the log itself!

1. Check permissions
2. Delete the table which is creating the issue(if it doesn't have any required data)
3. Try recovery after force crash

Restart services after whichever step you try.

If these don't work, then copy/export required data from MySQL and uninstall & reinstall.